# Events are not loading into the webix scheduler calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, webix

I want to show events in webix scheduler UNIT view But events are not getting displayed on calendar. My url is fine and receiving a successful response from the server with the data I need for the events. The response contains an array of events, and each event object has properties such as `id`, `title`, `start`, `end`, and `url`.

JSON response and code

```js
var data = {
  "response": "success",
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 46,
      "url": "",
      "title": "Jeremy Madison",
      "start": "2023/09/28 09:45:00 AM",
      "end": "2023/09/28 09:45:00 AM",
      "extendedProps": {
        "calendar": "business",
        "model": {
          "id": 46,
          "appointment_type": "medical",
          "user_id": 1,
          "service_id": 1,
          "patient_id": 20,
          "location_id": 1,
          "start": "2023-09-28 09:30:00",
          "end": "2023-09-28 09:45:00",
          "time": "9:30 AM",
          "duration": "15",
          "allDay": 0,
          "status": 0,
          "location": "peshawar",
          "mobile_no": "+1 (907) 769-9091\n",
          "clinician_name": "Sudais Khan",
          "patient_name": "Jeremy Madison"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
webix.ready(function () {
    webix.CustomScroll.init();
    var id = 1;
    var apiUrl = "schedules?nid=" + id;
    var eventsLoaded = false;
    var scheduler = webix.ui({
       view: "scheduler",
       container: "my_schedules",
       id: "myScheduler",
       width: 1000,
       height: 1000,
       save: "rest->" + apiUrl,
       url: apiUrl,
       monthSelect: true,
       weekHeader: true,
       events: new webix.DataCollection({
          scheme: {
             $init: function (obj) {
                obj.start_date = webix.Date.isDate(obj.start)
                   ? obj.start
                   : webix.Date.strToDate("%Y/%m/%d %H:%i")(obj.start);
                obj.end_date = webix.Date.isDate(obj.end)
                   ? obj.end
                   : webix.Date.strToDate("%Y/%m/%d %H:%i")(obj.end);
             },
          },
       }),
       on: {
          onBeforeEventSave: function (id, data, update) {
             if (update) {
                data.start = webix.Date.dateToStr("%Y/%m/%d %H:%i")(data.start_date);
                data.end = webix.Date.dateToStr("%Y/%m/%d %H:%i")(data.end_date);
             } else {
                data.start = webix.Date.dateToStr("%Y/%m/%d %H:%i")(data.start_date);
                data.end = webix.Date.dateToStr("%Y/%m/%d %H:%i")(data.end_date);
             }
          },
       },
    });
    scheduler.attachEvent("onViewChange", function (newView) {
       if (!eventsLoaded && newView === "month") {
          scheduler.clearAll(); 
          scheduler.load(apiUrl, "json");
          eventsLoaded = true;
       }
    });
 });
```

Comment: can you try by changing the dates format?

Answer (score 0):

To be displayed in Units, your events must have the unit property with the ID(s) of a unit(s). Provide this property, and everything will be fine.
Reference: https://docs.webix.com/scheduler__loading_data.html

Comment: Also, I don't think this part works. `events: new webix.DataCollection({` . To map properies onto other properties, you need to override the Backend service merhods, e.g. events() in this case. https://docs.webix.com/scheduler__backend.html#loadingdata Scheduler does not have `events` property. The only data-related property is `url`.

Comment: `save: "rest->" + apiUrl,` does not work either, Scheduler does not use DataProcessor at all.

Comment: `monthSelect: true,  weekHeader: true,` - no such settings, these might be from the small Calendar.

Comment: `onBeforeEventSave` - this too, To handle saving, you also need to extend Backend and maybe in some cases Operations service.

Comment: `onViewChange` - this too. To handle view change, you need to use the property of the reactive state - `mode`. https://docs.webix.com/scheduler__configuring.html#howtolistentochangesofthereactiveproperties

Comment: Can you please modify my code

Comment: I want to use "clinician_name" and location id as ids for units

Comment: Well, I could, but I should not. Here people are encouraged to solve problems on their own and ask specific questions when they are stuck on something specific. You should try and modify the code by yourself. Read the docs, they will help. if you have some problems along the way, feel free to ask. To test your code, use https://snippet.webix.com/scheduler

Comment: ...if you do not want to solve the problem yourself, you should contact Webix support team.

Comment: I tried almost all the approaches. But I am unable to resolve this issue. I will appreciate your help

Comment: What I meant is: follow all advice from the above comments, paste your best solution into a snippet, make it readable and working at least to some extent and then say "I followed your advice, this is what I have, and here is the problem (line of code)."